# Используя Python с VK API, как я могу получить чекины с определенной улицы?

Tags: python, вконтакте

Я пробую использовать [VK API places.getCheckins метод](http://vk.com/dev/places.getCheckins)  для получения чекинов с определенной улицы для последующего использования в анализе (настроений?). Этот метод требует указанные широту и долготу как параметры. Я скачал координаты некоторых улиц Москвы в формате GeoJSON. Выглядит примерно так:

```
{
 ...
 "properties": { 
     ...
     "name": "a-street-so-called", 
     ... 
  }, 
  "geometry": { 
     "type": "LineString", 
     "coordinates": [ 
         [ 37.399092526176915, 55.715745258737407 ], 
         [ 37.398983226159537, 55.715823964808216 ] 
     ] 
  } 
 }
```

И оставил их [здесь](https://transfer.sh/BFKUQ/moscow-russia-roads.geojson) (166 МБ).

Отсюда я получаю координаты определенной улицы с помощью скрипта:

```
def get_streets(name):
    coordinates = []
    for i in data['features']:
        try:
            if i['properties']['name'] == name:
                coordinates.append(i['geometry']['coordinates'])
        except:
            None
     return coordinates
```

Результат выглядит примерно так (я представляю это как "type": "LineString" в формате GeoJSON):

```
[
    [37.625916884336014, 55.67560424062041], 
    [37.62689513625539, 55.67304407211511], 
    [37.62689513625539, 55.67304407211511], 
    [37.627487820628794, 55.671551422797954], 
    [37.63091308536064, 55.66356606746359], 
    [37.631465368960754, 55.663102380580035],
    ...
]
```

Или если в файле улица встречается больше одного раза ("type":"MultiLineString"),  то так:

```
[
    [
        [37.625916884336014, 55.67560424062041], 
        [37.62689513625539, 55.67304407211511]
    ], 
    [
        [37.62689513625539, 55.67304407211511], 
        [37.627487820628794, 55.671551422797954],
        ...
    ], 
    [
        [37.63091308536064, 55.66356606746359], 
        [37.631465368960754, 55.663102380580035],
        ...
    ],
...
]
```

Между координатами на карте встречаются пробелы на прямых участках дорог:

[image]

Я пробую заполнить их линейно:

```
def calc_points(lat_0, lon_0, lat_1, lon_1):
    """
    The function takes in two coordinates and returns a
    list of new coordinates, which lie on the line between
    the first two.
    """
    new_points = []
    y_displacement = lat_0 - lat_1
    x_displacement = lon_0 - lon_1
    # Using the formula for a line: y = m * x + b.
    m = y_displacement / x_displacement
    b = lat_0 - m * lon_0
    x = lon_0
    if lon_1 > lon_0:
        while x < lon_1:
            x += 0.00001
            lat_new = round(m * x + b, 6)
            new_points.append((x, lat_new))
    elif lon_0 > lon_1:
        while x > lon_1:
            x -= 0.00001
            lat_new = round(m * x + b, 6)
            new_points.append((x, lat_new))
    return new_points
```

После я пробую все это автоматизировать:

```
def calc_streets(coordinates):
    j = 0
    # check if the coordinates list is nested
    if coordinates[0][0] != None:
        for i in coordinates:
            threshold = len(i) - 1
            while j < threshold:
                new = calc_points(i[j][1],
                                  i[j][0],
                                  i[j+1][1],
                                  i[j+1][0])
                coordinates.append(new)
                j += 1
    else:
        threshold = len(coordinates) - 1
        while j < threshold:
            new = calc_points(coordinates[j][1],
                              coordinates[j][0],
                              coordinates[j+1][1],
                              coordinates[j+1][0])
            coordinates.append(new)
            j += 1
```

Все это вынуждает меня задуматься, есть ли способ получить чекины легче? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Читая доки API ВКонтакте [places.getCheckins](https://vk.com/dev/places.getCheckins):

> идентификатор места. Игнорируется, если указаны latitude и longitude.

Следовательно, не надо скачивать всю базу мест, которая заняла у вас 166МБ.

Идем дальше. Вы пишите, что Вас интересует получение чекинов с определенной улицы.

Есть [places.search](https://vk.com/dev/places.search), который принимает в качестве поискового запроса строку с интересующей Вас улицей.

В итоге получаете идентификатор места, который потом можете использовать в **getCheckins()**.

Надеюсь, что помог.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но вот я пробую использовать этот метод для получения адресов домов рядом с Каширским шоссе и получаю [это](https://transfer.sh/SqOMp/screen-shot-2015-06-01-at-22.35.34.png) (количество геометок в полученным местах должны быть 1, 47, 7, соответственно). После пробую получить [ответ](https://transfer.sh/1bJiBd/screen-shot-2015-06-01-at-22.36.26.png) на первый идентификатор места, [на второй](https://transfer.sh/BbuN1/screen-shot-2015-06-01-at-22.36.56.png), [на третий](https://transfer.sh/1aEuVl/screen-shot-2015-06-01-at-22.37.19.png).

Что пошло не так?

Comment: @toshinogorlo у меня все получается, при `place_id` 213784. Может проблема на стороне ВК, в любом случае это уже другой вопрос.